# What is the backstory of Donkey?

Tags: character, shrek

Honestly, why did donkey follow Shrek? Did he not have a family or what? What's the back story of donkey? Where did he come from?

Comment: Shrek asks Donkey that first question in the film. Granted, Donkey answers in song, but I still think it's pretty clear.

Comment: Would you believe a talking donkey at first instance??? Somebody gotta find the back story of donkey.

Comment: Hi.  Please add comments here below your question.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: But it don't answer the question, where did he come from, and how on Earth can a donkey talk...he is a mystery that must be understood.

Answer (score 10):

The films don't really explain much about Donkey's life prior to the start of *Shrek 1*. All we get is his description of "the saddest thing[s] that ever happened to [him]" in *Shrek 2*:

> Oh man, where do I *begin*? Well, first there was the time that old farmer tried to sell me for some magic beans, I ain't ever gotten over that. Then this dude threw a party, and he had all the kids try to pin the tail on me. Then they all got *drunk*, and started beating me with a stick, going, "PINATA! PINATA!" What is a pinata, anyway?

From this, we can gather that Donkey has had a difficult life. Then, the first time we see him in *Shrek 1*, his owner is trying to sell him to Lord Farquaad's men for the reward money. He runs away, literally bumps into Shrek... and Shrek *actually stands up for him*, scaring Farquaad's men away.

As for why Donkey follows Shrek, or whether he has any other friends or family, he explains this himself:

> **SHREK:** Now, why don't you go celebrate your freedom with your own friends? Hmm?
>   **DONKEY:** But, uh, I don't have any friends. And I'm not goin' out there by myself. Hey, wait a minute! I got a great idea! I'll stick with you! You're a mean, green, fightin' machine. Together we'll scare the spit out of anybody that crosses us!

In other words, Donkey follows Shrek around and wants to befriend him partly for his (Donkey's) own protection, partly out of gratitude towards Shrek for saving him, and partly because he simply has no-one else to turn to.